# No main manifest attribute, in itextpdf-5.5.5.jar file

Tags: itext

I'm trying to use the "Itext" applications. I've downloaded the "jar" file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/ and trying to launch the file: itextpdf-5.5.5.jar but get an error: 
"no main manifest attribute, in itextpdf-5.5.5.jar"

Could you please help me and explain how can I launch it? It seems that there is no declared main class in the manifest.

Comment: Er... what do you mean by "launching" the jar? iText is a *library*, not an *executable*. What did you expect iText to do?

Comment: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding :) Tried to help my coworker and hadn't investigated the issue. My bad mistake.

Comment: OK, no problem. [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups) is the only iText tool that has a GUI. All the other jars are libraries that are built-in into software.